# Hide or Disable Crystal Report Parameter Panel

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that displays a bar code that will dynamically change.So I used a parameter for setting the image streaming URL and it works fine, but I don't want to show the parameter panel on the report. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `supress` option.. to supress the unwanted objects

Comment: How to suppress is there any option like in crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

try below to supress

`right click on the object and go to format --> Common --> check supress`

Comment: It will suppress the object, I want the object to display, but I want to hide the parameter panel.

Answer (score 0):

With your report open in CR, go to `File` → `Report Options` → Then uncheck `Show preview panel`. Note that this will also get rid of your report's group tree in the same panel.

To remove individual parameters from the panel, edit the parameter and set `Show on (viewer) Panel` to `Do not show`.

Comment: Hi the parameter prompt is still coming as a pop up, I want to avoid that

Comment: Parameters are intended for user input (hiding the parameter would defeat the point of having it there in the first place); if you don't want that box to pop up then you need to hard code the image streaming URL into the report.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to have a report with a suppressed parameter panel, in the case where one knows the defaults suffice. This might particularly be useful with parameters used for dev/testing, but which user's shouldn't see.